# How to secure endpoints and pages with Spring Security oAuth2 (Using auth0)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, auth0, spring-thymeleaf

I'd like to create two secured Spring Boot 3 projects:

- A REST API;
- A Front-end Project using Thymeleaf.

I'm fully aware I could just embed everything in the same project and make my life easier, but I want to decouple the back from the front end for future implementations in different languages.

As I want to keep things simple, I plan to use Auth0 (Okta) for it. There's plenty of documentation on how to protect Rest APIs. Auth0 also integrates seamlessly with Spring Boot.

I'm just wondering how I could go about authenticating on the front-end project and then adding the Authorization header to every call to the back-end. Is it even the correct way of doing it? Has anyone created anything similar?

Comment: Do all your authentication on the backend. It's easier and more secure. Here is an example:

- [Build a Beautiful CRUD App with Spring Boot and Angular](https://auth0.com/blog/spring-boot-angular-crud/)

Comment: I use Auth0 (and other providers) in [this set of tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials#securing-spring-applications-with-oauth2). You'll find there à solution with Thymeleaf client as well as one with BFF (for SPA when You'll be there).

Comment: And by the way, the tutorial from @MattRaible is suboptimal on several points. 1st, using client and resource server conf in the same filter-chain is a worst practice, but as resource server conf is not used in the app in the tutorial (OAuth2 tokens are not used), this is easy to fix: Just remove the dependency and the configuration). 2nd, rather than overriding the logout endpoint, implementing a logout success handler is probably better integrated with Spring Security. Last, serving Angular assets with Spring Boot app is probably not the most scallable / efficient option